# session is expiring even sending request to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication

when a user login I store his id in session let say in `Session["id"]`. on mostly pages I store id from session in an integer and use it in various methods. I put a check on page_load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["id"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    }
    //code goes here
}
```

What I know is that session expire after 20 min if no request is send to server. but even continuously sending request session expire and i redirected on home page. Is this correct approach or I should try other alternative. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Set SessionTime out in webconfig file and then try

Comment: default session timeout is 20 min but sometime I recive expire message in 1 minute

Comment: Are you sure you are using same context?

Comment: yes pretty sure pouya

Comment: Are you doing any IO operation in your application?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to use the [membership API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.ASPX) which handles all these details transparently. As shown in [this explanatory page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) you could directly set the timeout interval in membership API using a parameter in the web.config.

Hope I helped!

Comment: thanks for answering pantelis, till now I use role base security. I read it and try out

Answer (score 0):

If there is gap more than 20 minutes between two requests to server then only your session will get expired

Comment: I know this dhananjay i also mention it in question what i want to know is should i store id in session to use in content pages of user

Answer (score 0):

Use Permanent User Login Session In ASP.NET thi sample describes how to create a permanent user login session in ASP.NET. The sample code includes an ASP.NET MVC4 project to control the user registration and login process. But you can use this technique in any type of ASP.NET project. But briefly you can use this code

The functionality of this class is to add a form authentication ticket to the browser cookie collection with a life time expiry.

```
public sealed class CookieHelper
{
private HttpRequestBase _request;
private HttpResponseBase _response;

public CookieHelper(HttpRequestBase request, 
HttpResponseBase response)
{
    _request = request;
    _response = response;
}

//[DebuggerStepThrough()]
public void SetLoginCookie(string userName,string password,bool isPermanentCookie)
{
    if (_response != null)
    {
        if (isPermanentCookie)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket userAuthTicket = 
                new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, 
                DateTime.MaxValue, true, password,               FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            string encUserAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(userAuthTicket);
            HttpCookie userAuthCookie = new HttpCookie
                (FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encUserAuthTicket);
            if (userAuthTicket.IsPersistent) userAuthCookie.Expires = 
                    userAuthTicket.Expiration;
            userAuthCookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
            _response.Cookies.Add(userAuthCookie);
        }
        else
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, isPermanentCookie);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This function is used in login page or control on the click of login button. In the attached sample project, the following function is written in AccountController class. This function validates the login of the user and then add a permanent form authentication ticket to the browser.

```
private bool Login(string userName, string password,bool rememberMe)
{
if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
{
    CookieHelper newCookieHelper = 
    new CookieHelper(HttpContext.Request,HttpContext.Response);
    newCookieHelper.SetLoginCookie(userName, password, rememberMe);
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}
```